# Completion of abelian extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

I don't understand this step in a proof:

> Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an abelian extension, $p$ a ramified prime and
>   $K_p$ the completion at that prime. Then $K_p/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is
>   abelian.

Why does this hold?

<s>I'm also curious about the situation when $p$ is unramified.</s>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an identification of $\mathrm{Gal}(K_p/\mathbf{Q}_p)$ with the decomposition group of a prime lying above $p$ (regardless of the ramification at $p$).

Comment: Any unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ is cyclic. So the theorem is only really saying something if $p$ is ramified.